# Probability of at least one event

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 2 independent events, probability that Exam A is a success is 0.4. Probability that Exam B is a success is 0.7. What is the probability that at least one of these is a success.

So I thought the way 'at-least- one of these is a success is 'a is a success' or 'b is a success' or 'a and b is a success'. But the answer is  'a is a success' or 'b is a success' - 'a and b is a success'. I am confused as to why this is.

Comment: The answer is correct. It should be $0.7+0.4-0.7\times0.4$ because the area $P(A\cap B)$ is counted twice when you add them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could think of *at least one of these is a success* is any of

- *a is a success and b is a failure*
- *b is a success and a is a failure*
- *a and b are each a success*

and add up the probabilities.  That will give you the correct answer.

You could note that the probability that *a is a success and b is a failure* or *a and b are each a success* is equal to the probability that *a is a success*, and similarly  the probability that *b is a success and a is a failure* or *a and b are each a success* is equal to the probability that *b is a success*.

Then adding together the probability that *a is a success* and the probability that *b is a success* will count the probability that *a and b are each a success*  twice.  So to get the correct answer, you will need to subtract the probability that *a and b are each a success*.

This is called the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 3):

The probability of at least one of the events occurring is the total probability minus the probability that none occur.

In this case, use $1-$(Prob. of failed A)$\times$(Prob. of failed B)

This is equal to $1-(0.6)\times(0.3)=1-0.18=0.82$ or $82$%